# How to add some white space at the end of a flow document using LineBreak?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, flowdocument

Hi I have a FlowDocument in a WPF app.

When printing FlowDocument I need to add some white space at the end of the latest block added (BlockUIContainer)

At the moment I am using this code, but no space has been added and no errors.

Any idea how to do it? Any other better approach?

```
              flowDoc.Blocks.Add(new BlockUIContainer(imgVoucher));
                flowDoc.Blocks.Add(cntTxtSection);
                flowDoc.Blocks.Add(new BlockUIContainer(imgBarcode));
                flowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new LineBreak()));
                flowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new LineBreak()));
                flowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new LineBreak()));
                flowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new LineBreak()));
```

Comment: Probably a silly comment but if you don't have anything after the LineBreak how do you know space was not added?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a great deal about Flow Documents however from a quick Google search you can add margins to a block..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.margin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Margin looks like this: (Left, Top, Right, Bottom)

```
Margin="0,0,0,10"
```

A margin better fits your requirement than adding multiple line breaks which is semantically incorrect.